# PHP/SQL query will not execute

Tags: php, html

Hello for some reason the SQL query will not run and it will not delete the row in the database. I was wondering if anyone has any idea why this is?

***choosebid.php***:

```
<td>
  <form method = "POST" action= "actionpage9.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['bid_id']?>" name="bid_id" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary" value ="decline" />
  </form>
</td>
```

***actionpage9.php***:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

$bid_id    = $_POST['bid_id'];

$query   = "DELETE FROM bid WHERE 'bid_id' = '$bid_id'";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
}

header("location: choosebid.php");
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Did you try to replace the `Delete` by a `Select` and see if you get any results?

Comment: what is the response you got?, or error from your logs

Comment: The hidden field value is a number or character (string) ?

Comment: Remove the header() and check whether any errors are shown!

Comment: Did you try to echo value of `$bid_id` or  echo your `$query' variable

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL statement from delete to drop